# Formatting for print consistent across browsers

Tags: css, printing, pdf-generation, media-queries, haml

I've been spending a great deal of time lately working on css/media css to get print consistency across browsers. We have customers still using IE 7, 8, 9, as well as Chrome and Firefox. The problem I'm having is that I cannot assume what browser is being used. (Printing in IE 8 can be a nightmare, as many clients have group policy settings that prevent the browser from writing to a temp path used for generation of the print output.)

The HTML is being rendered in HAML--And I cannot remove that, because the printed templates must appear on the screen with the option of being printed.

I'm looking for some solution where I don't have to re-engineer the existing haml. Perhaps some sort of print link that sends a message to use the HAML to put together a PDF on the server side. Maybe I could run some portion of webkit on the server that handles print requests and sends a pdf to the client.

Wondering if anyone here has any good ideas for a problem such as this. If I can consistently generate the print output on the server in a way that I have control over the problem would be solved.

Thanks in advance...